# Bootstrap modal running once plus once for every previous time it was opened

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I'm making a simple Gazetteer application. I open a modal by clicking on a marker which opens up with a photo of the city the marker is on.

It works as intended the first time I select a city. Any subsequent times clicking any marker will loop through the modal code as many times as it has been opened previously.

```
markers.on('click', function (e) {
    city = e.layer.options.title
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        //BELOW THIS LINE IS WHERE LOOPING OCCURS
        var modal = $(this);
        $.when(runAjax('City Reference', 'source/php/getCityInfo.php', 'POST',city))
        .then(function() {
             cityReference = ajaxResponse.place_id;
             $.when(runAjax('Photo Reference', 'source/php/getPhotoRef.php', 'GET', cityReference))
             .then(function() {
                 photoReference = ajaxResponse.photoR;
                 modal.find('.modal-body').html('<img src=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=' + photoReference + '&input=green%20lanes&sensor=false&types=(regions)&key=<<<HIDDEN>>>&maxwidth=400&maxheight=400></div>');
            });
        });
        
        modal.find('.modal-title').html('<b>' + city + '</b>');
    }) // ABOVE THIS LINE IS WHERE LOOPING STOPS
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

I have no understanding as to why this is happening.

Comment: You've set it up so that every time you get a click, another `show.bs.model` handler is added.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. How do I prevent this?

Comment: This may have something to see with bubbling, as it seems like there are nested listeners. Please refer to https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation. This is an humble hint, as I don't use jQuery at all I prefer letting an expert answer.

Comment: Probably move the entire `show.bs.modal` handler out of the `click` handler.

Comment: That makes sense. It works and now I learned a little bit about it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Ouroborus comment, I just moved the show.bs.model to underneath the click handler:

```
  
  
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        
        var modal = $(this);
        $.when(runAjax('City Reference', 'source/php/getCityInfo.php', 'POST',city))
        .then(function() {
             cityReference = ajaxResponse.place_id;
             $.when(runAjax('Photo Reference', 'source/php/getPhotoRef.php', 'GET', cityReference))
             .then(function() {
                 photoReference = ajaxResponse.photoR;
                 modal.find('.modal-body').html('<img src=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=' + photoReference + '&input=green%20lanes&sensor=false&types=(regions)&key=<<<HIDDEN>>>&maxwidth=400&maxheight=400></div>');
            });
        });
        
        modal.find('.modal-title').html('<b>' + city + '</b>');
    });
    markers.on('click', function (e) {
        city = e.layer.options.title
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
```